# Arranging Axios response data to fit my TypeScript interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, axios

I've created an interface called 'ServerData', which holds one object - song data that I request from the Musixmatch API.
I would like to fetch a song with Axios and then place it initialState, but as I'm new to interfaces, I'm not sure how to manipulate my response so that it can fit the ServerData interface.

When I hover over the error, it says:
`Type '{ randomSong: object; }' is not assignable to type 'never'`

In case it's relevant, before I added TypeScript to the project the Axios fetch was working fine, my frontend was able to get the song data, only then I wasn't using interfaces so there was no issue.

[Picture of the code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnRAs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message that you are receiving, the problem isn't the type of the axios response -- it's the type of `setInitialState`.  It's telling you that `setInitialState` can only accept an empty array (`never[]`).

I'm guessing `setInitialState` is coming from a `useState` hook?  You don't always need to set the generic when calling `useState` because some times it can be properly inferred from the initial value, but in this case you do.  Typescript can't possibly know what type are elements are allowed to be included in an array when the initial array is empty.  You have to tell it.

Change your `useState` call to include the generic like this:

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState<ServerData[]>([]);
```